# React Router: How to re-render the page when the user presses the back button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I'm hoping there's a simple answer. I've tried different things and searched all over but I still haven't been able to fix the issue.

SO!
Using React-Router-Dom, I have a parent component with a logo that is in a fixed position and seen on all the child components/pages.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
        {window.location.pathname==='/contact' ? 
         null :
         <div className='originalLogo'></div>
        }
       </div>
```

)
 }
}

But on the Contact page, the logo is replaced with a modified version and the original is set to null.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return (
      <div className='modifiedLogo'></div>
  )
```

}
}

I'm able to capture this change when the user manually clicks on the contact page through the menu. But here is where the issue starts. If the user opens up the menu bar and clicks to the homepage, the logo changes back to its original version. BUT if the user clicks 'BACK' on the browser from the contact page, the logo stays as the modified version instead of the original version. It's only until the user clicks on the menu at the homepage, which will cause the page to re-render due to the state change (of the menu display), and then the logo will go back to its original form.

So my question is, how do I re-render the page when the user clicks the 'BACK' button on the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Switch` and `Route` components to render not only pages, but also page parts. This should help with the problem.

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/contact" render={() => null} />
                <Route render={() => <div className='originalLogo' />} />
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This definitely helped! Thank you!
What I ended up doing for the logo, was use the ternary operator to set the z-index of the logo. On the contact page, the z-index of the original logo goes -1, then the modified logo goes to 1. And then on the main page the original logo stays at 1. I couldn't use the render function for the logo because I would have to repeat that code for every single page it renders on, not just the contact page.
I ended up using the render function for the menu bars themselves since the contact page is the only one where it changes color. Thanks again